# Prevent iOS Device from Sleeping

Tags: ios, sleep-mode

I’m trying to prevent a device from sleeping - setting auto-lock to “never” works on some devices (iPhone 6, 11.0) but not others (iPhone 10, 11.2.6). I’ve tried setting `application.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`, but that doesn’t seem to have any effect. Does anyone know of a solution to prevent a device from sleeping regardless of the device and iOS version?

Comment: actually it's **application.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true**

Comment: If you do this in the app delegate, specifically `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`, you already have access to the application, so I think `application.isIdleTimerDisabled = true` should suffice